# calls to external web api Access-Control-Allow-Origin error 502 nodejs

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

I need to call an external web api which runs on the same server as my application, but don't get permission to do so. When I run the application locally, it works fine. But when I deploy it, error 502 on every remote request.

I searched to the suggested questions when I made this question.

Is it possible to have the same issue as him: [Steam API Access-Control-Allow-Origin Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861871/steam-api-access-control-allow-origin-issue)

Comment: yes this CORS issue

Comment: i have all the necessary headers. `router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
}); `

Comment: can you show the code how you calling external API ?

Answer (score 0):

Because there was no way around this problem. We hosted everything on the same server, so there couldn't occur an Access control allow origin error.